# Forgetoolkit AR/VR Toolkit

Tags: autodesk-forge

I asked the question earlier this year.
Since you are currently promoting the ForgeToolkit again, I would be interested in a roadmap. The project is no longer listed among the beta projects of Autodesk and you won't find more information about it anywhere.

Is the project still being worked on? If so, can you participate in it?

I would like to use the toolkit much more intensively, but due to the current limitation of the size of the 3D models I cannot do this.

I would be happy to get an update on the project status.
I would also like to participate in the development or test new version, if that is desired.

Comment: I've contacted the author of the library asking for some feedback. As far as I know the future of the project (whether it'll get integrated into Forge or open-sourced) is still not clear. For the time being, if you're running into any issues with the toolkit, I'd still recommend https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-convert-utils as the alternative approach.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I am looking forward to the feedback.
Forge-convert-utils is now my daily companion. Thanks for the really good tool!

Comment: Did you get any feedback yet?

Comment: Hey @FlorolF, I had a chat with the AR/VR Toolkit author, and the response was: the big question (whether the toolkit will be open sourced or officially integrated into Forge) is still being discussed, and due to several (internal) pending requirements we will *not* be able to provide a decision before the end of the year.

Comment: @PetrBroz , any news about AR/VR Toolkit jet?

Comment: Hi @FloroIF, please take a look at this talk from Autodesk University 2020: https://www.autodesk.com/autodesk-university/conference/theater-talks?wchannelid=uy0j8i3r0u&wmediaid=qg8swbeafy, where Nicolas Fonta talks about the future for XR.

Comment: Thank you @PetrBroz
If I have understood correctly, there will be cooperations with third-party providers in the future. Remote rendering with Nvidia, VR collobaration and XR on site with Unity.
This means that the AR/VR Toolkit will not be developed further and in the future you will need a license for Unity Reflect to get a pipeline from Revit->Unity?